# How to enable mouse click word selection in emacs console mode

Tags: bash, emacs, cygwin, elisp

How can I customize emacs (version 24/ cygwin / shell mode)
so that when a word is double clicked with the mouse, that
word is selected/highlighted.

Comment: In the future, please take care when tagging your question. This has *nothing at all* to do with [tag:intellij-idea] or [tag:linux]. Tagging with [tag:cygwin] would be a much better idea. (I have done this for you this time.)

Comment: If you are running emacs inside a terminal (cygwin) you cannot modify emacs to handle this, nor can any program. That up to the terminal.